# Strange output of pwdLastSet

Tags: python, python-ldap

Some of AD accounts are inactive and their pwdLastSet is equal to 0.
However, when I'm trying to calculate password age for accounts, this inactive accounts gave me a last possible date `1601-01-01 00:00:00+00:00`

Here is how it looks like:

```
current_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
start_date = user_details[0].pwdLastSet.value 
if  start_date == 0:
    password_age = 'NULL'
else:
    password_age = current_date - start_date
    print(password_age)
```

Comment: NTFS timestamps are offset from 1601-01-01 at midnight UTC - it means the value of the directory attribute is 0, likely because someone tried to "reset" it to trigger password expiration

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen in other words, that "reset" cause a problem to me. Any clue how to handle it? I tried other attributes of AD, without a result.

Comment: what is the actual `start_date` value in that case? Assuming it's `-1` or `None` or similar: simply take it into account, eg. `if start_date <= 0` or `if not start_date`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `start_date` value is not set rigidly, but rather it takes from `user_details[0].pwdLastSet.value` which is attribute in AD account.

Comment: Alright, what is the actual `user_details[0].pwdLastSet.value` value in that case?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen depends on the AD account, to be honest. For example if account expired, you could expect attribute 0. When account is active, then attribute is a date.